# How to create and maintain a receiver buffer for a network simulation framework?

Tags: matlab, networking

I am trying to simulate a mesh network in matlab. The intermediate nodes and destination need to maintain a receiver buffer so that whenever a packet arrives from a source, it is stored in the buffer and can be used for further operations. I am using a main file and the source, intermediate and destination nodes are functions. Since functions are called everytime a new packet arrives, how and where can I maintain a individual or combined buffer for reception? The packets cant be treated on a first come first served basis but need to be collectively buffered.Please ask if I haven't explained the problem correctly.

Comment: Can you clarify on how you model packets? How about sharing the relevant parts of your code?